# populate external object data in AlpacaJs table

Tags: alpacajs

I am new to Alpaca, I am trying to push data into alpaca table.
looking through http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/fields/table.html, instead of passing direct data I want to populate external data. how can I define datasource there?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get dynamic data from server or file you should use the property dataSource like this:

```
"dataSource": "___URL_TO_YOUR_DATASOURCE___"
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/jzustqfL/) with for this. I took the example from Alpaca website and I hosted a simple json file that contains the data to bind to the table object.

If you have many fields don't forget to assign the data to your field name `(example "myTable": [_the_array_of_data_], "anotherField": "some_data"... )`